# Как тут правильно сделать array_search или что то вроде?

Tags: php, массивы

есть 2 массива

Первый -

```
Array ( 
  [0] => 53 
  [1] => 55 
  [2] => 56 )
```

Второй -

```
Array ( 
  [0] => stdClass Object ( [list_id] => 53 ) 
  [1] => stdClass Object ( [list_id] => 55 ) 
  [2] => stdClass Object ( [list_id] => 56 ) )
```

Как мне сделать поиск значений из первого массива во втором. 
Пробовал

```
foreach ($array1 as $obj) {
    if ( array_search($obj->list_id, $array2) === false ) {
         $newArray[] = $obj-list_id;
    } 
}
```

Не сработало...

Comment: `$obj-list_id` это опечатка или как ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Array ( 
  [0] => 53 
  [1] => 55 
  [2] => 56 )
```

в 1-м у тебя числа, во втором объекты

```
     foreach ($array2 as $obj) {
//if( in_array($obj->id,$array1)){
// $resultArray[] = $obj;
//}    
            foreach ($array1 as $item) {
                if ($item == $obj->id) {         
                     $resultArray[] = $obj;
                } 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ну так этот вариант работать не будет... Всегда будет находиться   $obj->id, который равен $item

Comment: @RattleSneyk погоди как он может всегда находить, у тебя например массив 4, 5, 7, соответственно выберет только объекты с этими id

Comment: Ну я не правильно выразился. =) В общем  if ($item == $obj->id) не работает.
а array_diff, array_intersect пробовал ? - Да. Тоже не работает. Ошибку выдает
:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in

Comment: @RattleSneyk $item - по твоему вопросу, это число из массива чисел, $obj->id это тоже число == должно сработать, напиши (int)$obj->id. array_diff сработает только с одинаковыми типами данных в массиве

Comment: Вроде бы сработало..=)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
// array1 - массив чисел
// array2 - массив объектов
$result = array_filter($array2, function($e) use ($array1) {
    return in_array($e->list_id, $array1); 
});
```